# "this" keyword for const variable in initialising list

Tags: c++

Why cant we use `this` in initialization list like this?
It threw an error cant find `{` before `this`..
But scope is not the problem because the second code works

```
class Student {
public :
    int age;
    const int rollNumber;
    int &x;     // age reference variable

    Student(int r, int age) : rollNumber(r), this->age(age), x(this -> age) {
        //rollNumber = r;
    }
```

"This" one works:

```
class Student {
public :
    int age;
    const int rollNumber;int &x;


    Student(int r, int age) : rollNumber(r), x(this -> age) {
        //rollNumber = r;
    }
```

I know we have to declare and initialize `const` and reference variables at same time but I want to initialize them after taking an input and passing to my objects

Comment: Are you sure your second example works?  I don't see a declaration for `x`.

Comment: Also, note that members will be initialized in the order that they are declared in the class; you should keep your member initializer lists in the same order to avoid accidentally invoking UB.

Comment: @0x5453 yes it should have been declared .just edited that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is "this is how it was decided the syntax would be", but from a philosophical standpoint, you might say that `this->age` does not exist in the initializer list (since you did not construct `this` yet...). Just:

```
age(age)
```

is the correct syntax, and it is clear from the context which `age` is which here.

Comment: I get that. You said that we haven't constructed `this` yet (before the scope of constructor in initialization list) But it shouldn't work for reference variable &x too. I think we can just say its how the syntax was decided ! Thankyou

Comment: @sarthakbansal I agree there is some inconsistency there, but it can be philosophied-away too (as most things :) ) - From context, `age` in the parenthesis should be the argument `age`, so if we did not allow **only** in the references to explicitly reference `this->member`, we could not initialize the reference (well we could, to the temporary argument, which makes no sense)! Of course it would make no sense for anything but a reference or a pointer. It does cause some confusion though.